# Online YUI Comperssor : How to interpret errors?

Tags: javascript, yui

To minify scripts I use the online YUI compressor available [here](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/).
Unfortunately though, from time to time the compressor throws errors that I cannot understand, especially since the script doesn't crash when being run.

e.g.:

```
[ERROR] 27:39:missing formal parameter    
[ERROR] 27:39:missing } after function body    
[ERROR] 31:13:identifier is a reserved word    
[ERROR] 32:8:syntax error
```

By the way, the script I was just trying to minify is on http://picselbocs.com/plugins/digitize/digitize.js

Answer (score 0):

I Just found out that in the case of the script above, I was using the "char" reserved word throughout my script extensively, which caused the minification to break.
Anyway, to better understand errors in compressing javascript code you should be using http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home, it provides much more detailed explanations.

Comment: You can check the validity of js code by running jslint before the  compression. http://jslint.com/